# Cannot resolve method 'getEvent()'

Tags: java, android

I am making an adapter class for my custom list view. However, when trying to retrieve from my Events' class, it says "Cannot resolve method 'getEvent()'" How do I fix this? It revolves over the 3 methods I'm trying to retrieve from. getEvent, getDate and getTime.
This is my Adapter class:

```js
public class EventsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Events> {

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;


    public EventsListAdapter(@NonNull Context context,@LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Events> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }


    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        String event = getItemId(position).getEvent();
        String date = getItemId(position).getDate();
        String time = getItemId(position).getTime();

        Events events = new Events(event,date,time);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView tvEvent =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView21);
        TextView tvTime =  (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview31);

        tvEvent.setText(event);
        tvDate.setText(date);
        tvTime.setText(time);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And this is my Events class:

```js
public class Events {

    private String event;
    private String date;
    private String time;

    public Events(String event, String date, String time){
        this.event = event;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;

    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `getView` method:

```
    String event = getItemId(position).getEvent();
    String date = getItemId(position).getDate();
    String time = getItemId(position).getTime();
```

As documentation, `getItemId` returns a `long`:

> long  getItemId(int position)
>
> Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.

This is why you get the error: you can't call `getEvent` on a `long`.

You are probably looking for the method `getItem`, which returns `T` (`Events`, in your case) by giving it the position of the element you want to get:

> T getItem(int position)
>
> Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

It might be that it's returning a generic object, so it needs casting to your class.

Try

```
String event = ((Events)getItemId(position)).getEvent();
```